# How to set minimun date and time in ionic 3

Tags: datetime, ionic3, toisostring

I want to set min date and time to ion-datetime. But I am not able to set it without converting that to toISOString().
If I am converting to toISOString() then time is not setting the exact time. It is setting the 5.30 hr previous time.

```
 <ion-datetime text-center placeholder="Start Date"
   pickerFormat="MMM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A" displayFormat="MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A" min="{{startDate}}"></ion-datetime>


   startDate: any;

   this.startDate = new Date().toISOString();
```

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Did you take into account the timezone?

Comment: Yes I need to display time aswell @RaulSauco

Answer (score 0):

You can use the moment library for this and set max date like:

```
 this.startDate = moment.utc(new Date()).local().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS');
```

and `ion-datetime` does not compare time part.

Comment: I want to display both date and time as well @haresh hanat

Comment: You can set pickerFormat="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"

Comment: I have to pick in 12 hours format. so I am using like this.
pickerFormat="DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm" .But in your solution format is this format('YYYY-MM-DD') ,this is not working

Comment: use this: moment.utc(new Date()).local().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS');

Comment: This is returning in 24hours format. I want to pick in 12 hours format

Comment: then set hour part in lower case like: pickerFormat="DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197675/discussion-between-ananya-and-haresh-hanat).